# Appending to a scraped data to a JSON file

Tags: python, json, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a json file from the scraped data. However based on my function converToJson() it keeps overwriting the previous entry and not appending. Is it because I'm not iterating over it? For example: The below Json file will just overwrite the first entry every time with new data instead of appending to it.

**[{"Volume": "Volume:\n6,061,086", "Price": "$ 41.88", "Name": "Suncor Energy Inc."}]**

```
def getStockDetails(url, browser):
    
        print(url)
        browser.get(url)
    
        quote_wrapper = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.quote-wrapper')
        quote_name = quote_wrapper.find_element_by_class_name(
            "quote-name").find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
        quote_price = quote_wrapper.find_element_by_class_name("quote-price").text
        quote_volume = quote_wrapper.find_element_by_class_name(
            "quote-volume").text
    
        print("\n")
        print("Quote Name: " + quote_name)
        print("Quote Price: " + quote_price)
        print("Quote Volume: " + quote_volume)
        print("\n")
    
        convertToJson(quote_name,quote_price,quote_volume)
 
  
 def convertToJson(quote_name,quote_price,quote_volume):
        quotesArr = []
        quoteObject = {
            "Name": quote_name,
            "Price": quote_price,
            "Volume": quote_volume
        }
        quotesArr.append(quoteObject)

        with open('trendingQuoteData.json', 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(quotesArr, outfile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make variables `quotesArr` global, put it outside function and write your json when it finished.

```
quotesArr = []
def convertToJson(quote_name,quote_price,quote_volume):
    quoteObject = {
        "Name": quote_name,
        "Price": quote_price,
        "Volume": quote_volume
    }
    quotesArr.append(quoteObject)

def trendingBot(url, browser):
    browser.get(url)
    trending = getTrendingQuotes(browser)
    for trend in trending:
        getStockDetails(trend, browser)
    # requests finished, write json to file
    with open('trendingQuoteData.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(quotesArr, outfile)
```

Comment: Yo, you've been a major help to me haha!

Comment: Some additional questions I had.. I want to take the information I scraped and output it on a website I will later create, Is creating this JSON file the appropriate way to go about doing this? Also I want my scraper to scrape maybe like every 6 hours, is that possible?

Comment: because I like your questions :D

Comment: Or should I make an entire new question and ask there?

Comment: for website feed I will scrape directly ajax requests see [here](https://app.tmxmoney.com/w3/viewTrend/api.php?action=getTopQuotesJSON) for trending and element in details page for example `quote-name` can be scraped using beautifulsoup or regex.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. Could you explain a little more...Is the way I'm doing it now, not correct?

Comment: How did you get to that page as well? haha

Comment: sorry misunderstand your question, yes JSON is good output format. You can view the URL in browser network console.

Comment: yes possible with cronjob but I'm not recommend to use selenium in this situation because what I've said above.

Comment: Ok so I use selenium already. So what you're saying I'd have to tell selenium to go directly to the ajax requests and get the information every let's say 6 hours?

Comment: Also, since I have the JSON file. I can now use the information from there to output on my personal website by using html and style it with css? If this is possible, based on what your saying, I'd want my JSON file to automatically update every 6 hours? I hope I didn't confuse you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185017/discussion-between-ewwink-and-pennyboy).

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

a = json.loads(jsonStringA)
b = json.loads(jsonStringB)
c = dict(a.items() + b.items())
# or c =  dict(a, **b)
```